# Is there a way to define the pin with an input?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3, dmx512, pi4j

I'm trying to program a kind of `dmx controller`, therefore I got a `RaspberryPi` and now I want to write a program to controlle a GPIO with `pi4j`. The idea is to ask for the GPIO that should be the output, save it in a int and reuse this to tell `pi4j` which GPIO I would like to be the Output.

Sorry for the bad code :)

I'm a native Germanspeaker so the `println` are in German.

```
System.out.println("GPIO des DMX Outputs :");

BufferedReader br_dmx_out = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

int dmx_out = Integer.parseInt(br_dmx_out.readLine());

System.out.println("Der DMX Output GPIO ist also GPIO " + dmx_out);         

// GPIO Controll

String predef = ""+dmx_out;
/*
String def = MessageFormat.format("RaspiPin.GPIO_0{0}",predef);
System.out.println(def);
*/
Pin pin_dmx = "RaspiPin.GPIO_0"+ predef;

GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

GpioPinDigitalOutput dmx_output = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(pin_dmx);
```

Normaly you code:

> GpioPinDigitalOutput dmx_output = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_01);

Java says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Pin

    at test.main(test.java:44)
```

I also tried a `switch/case` but this wouldn't either

```
GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

switch(dmx_out)
{
case 2:
    GpioPinDigitalOutput dmx_output = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02);
    break;
```

Java's error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    Duplicate local variable dmx_output
    dmx_output cannot be resolved
    dmx_output cannot be resolved

    at test.main(test.java:59)
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Pin

 at test.main(test.java:44)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a String to the Pin interface.

https://pi4j.com/1.2/apidocs/com/pi4j/io/gpio/Pin.html

To get an implementation of it you might want to call the constructor of [PinImpl](https://pi4j.com/1.2/apidocs/com/pi4j/io/gpio/impl/PinImpl.html) as in the following example:

https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/blob/master/pi4j-gpio-extension/src/main/java/com/pi4j/gpio/extension/mcp/MCP3204Pin.java